# What's the proper, most up-to-date way to handle configuration changes during background work?

Tags: android

I'd like to perform relatively short (2-3 seconds at most) background tasks while showing a `ProgressDialog` to the user (i'd like to show the `ProgressDialog` at the start of the task and dismiss it at the end).

I've tried several approaches, but all of them have downsides which i cannot solve properly.

What i have tried:

- `AsyncTask`

  The memory leak issue can be solved by using a `WeakReference` (to hold a reference to the `Activity`), but i cannot call back to the **new** `Activity` instance if it got re-created while the task is running (in case of an orientation change for example).
- `AsyncTask` wrapped in a headless `Fragment`:

  Commiting `Fragment` transactions outside of `onCreate()` often gives me the `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` `IllegalStateException`.

  Using `commitAllowingStateLoss()` does not feel like a proper solution.

  Adding the `Fragment` in `onCreate()` means it is attached to the `Activity` even if i don't need it at all, which feels like a huge overkill.

  It is a pain in the ass to implement, for example if i have several `AsyncTask`s. I have to either create a huge `Fragment` that contains several `AsyncTask` inner classes, which doesn't feel right, or create separate `Fragments` for each task, which is kinda hard to manage and results in confusing code.
- `IntentService` + `LocalBroadcastManager`

  My problem with this approach is even if i register my receiver as early as possible (in `onCreate()`, and unregister it in `onDestroy()`), it is still possible that the broadcast comes during an orientation change, **after `onDestroy()` and before `onCreate()`**, and so i miss the broadcast.

  (sticky broadcasts are deprecated and should not be used according to Google)

I don't really understand why Google makes it so hard to handle configuration changes.

How should i do this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJava is kind of overkill for just doing background work, and doesn't really fix the problems mentioned in the original post.
My favourite approach for anything that needs to run in background and be retained is [Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html). This is designed to be lifecycle aware, is easy to rebind the new Activity and results will be delivered either immediately or as soon as you rebind (never while stopped or during recreation).

This won't fix the fragment state loss issue, and there's no generic way to fix this if you need to change fragments in response to async work. Either use CommitAllowingStateLoss and make sure you fix the state on the next resume, or change the design so the progress is shown inline (See comments from Dianne Hackborn [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dXZZjhRjkMk))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried RxJava? It's quite tricky library for reactive functional programming but I have used it for some time and it's rewarding.

Have a look at that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is very old technic, you should use rxJava library for organizing concurrent work. With it you can start job on one thread, do work on another and process result on some other threads. It also has two default thread pools and you can do everything on a single thread.
Activity and Fragment is just a UI which, by the way, depend on screen orientation and device state (app visible or minimized). IntentService allow to execute background task and it has its own background thread, but, it will be stopped once job is complete. 
So, if I got it right, you need to notify your activity about yask status by sending broadcasts from IntentService. 
There is a better solution- you can start ordinary Service first and then bind Activity to it. During binding process you'll get your Service's interface and will be able to address to Service directly. Inside Service organize background tasks by using rxJava library.
See chapter 4 in this tutorial to get familiar with concurrency features: https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava